# .post requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use routes but it's throwing an error.

its working without routes, so there must be some problem in routes,
Would you mind helping me?

**index.js  (routes folder)**

```
 module.exports = function(events){
                var mongoose = require('mongoose');
                var loadSchema = require('../schemas/index');
                var functions={};
               // save function
               functions.saveEvent = function (req, res) {
        //schema loading
            new loadSchema({
                name:req.body.organizer,
                email:req.body.email,
                address:req.body.address,
                street:req.body.street,
                price:req.body.price,
                category:req.body.category,
                otherInfo:req.body.otherInfo
            }).save(function(error,data){
                if(error)
                    res.json(error);
                else
                    res.send("Event Saved");
            });
        };
          return functions;
      }
```

**app.js**

```
app.post('/addEvent',routes.saveEvent); // addEvent is the action of form
```

**index.js (schemas folder)**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    module.exports = mongoose.model('user', {
        name: Number,
        email: String,
        favoriteBook: String,
        password: String,
        confimrPassword: String
        });


    module.exports=mongoose.model('event',{
        organizer:String,
        email:String,
        address:String,
        street:String,
        category:String,
        price:String,
        otherInfo:String
    })
```

> Error: .post requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

Comment: Please format your post better. It's really hard to read whats going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.js (routes folder) exposes a function that returns your other middleware functions. If you want to have access to the middleware functions you need to invouke your exported function in index. JS:

Change

`app.post('/addEvent',routes.saveEvent);`

to

`app.post('/addEvent',routes().saveEvent);`